# Transform all elements of a list of strings to upper case

Tags: java, java-8

I want to transform a list of strings to upper case.

Here's my code to do this:

```java
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("abc", "def", "ghi");
List<String> upped = list.stream().map(String::toUpperCase).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Is there a simpler/better way to do this?

Comment: There's always another way. Like a for loop. What sort of answer are you looking for?

Comment: You could [use butterflies](https://xkcd.com/378/).

Comment: Note that a better way would be not to rely on `toUpperCase` but use `toUpperCase(locale)`.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You have not actually transformed the list; you have created a new list.

To transform the list in one small method call, use [`List#replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-):

```
list.replaceAll(String::toUpperCase);
```

Comment: Does this actually assign the transformed Strings to their respectful positions in the list? I only ask because I'm used to the string format `s=s.replaceAll()` but I'm not familiar with this implementation for List. Sounds like good info :)

Comment: @CalvinP.yes - it performs an in-place conversion on each element using the provided lambda, so element order is preserved.

Comment: amazing.  how does one learn that 'String::toUpperCase'  works.  :)

Comment: @john `String::toUpperCase` is a [*method reference*](https://www.baeldung.com/java-method-references-read). In short, if a method takes the same params as the lambda, its reference can be used instead. Instance methods that take no parameters qualify as a taking a parameter of the instance type. I could have coded `s -> s.toUpperCase` with the same effect, but using a method ref is preferable as it *names* the lambda expression. In this case, the meaning of a lambda is clear, but for more complicated lambdas it's easier the read when bundled into a well named method and its reference used