# when to use map and forEach

Tags: java, java-stream

I am learning Java 8 and came across a situation. Where in I have to iterate over a list of strings and then convert them to upperCase. The possible solutions would be to stream the list. Among many suggestions from Intellij the below two seems to be useful.

```
list.stream()
.map(String::toUpperCase)
```

or

```
list.stream().
forEach(p -> p.toUpperCase())
```

I am confused on which one to use and the use cases for all the Suggestions. Can I get help regarding which method to use and how to understand using all those suggestions?

Comment: `map()` does nothing without a terminal operation. `forEach(p -> p.toUpperCase())` is a terminal operation that does nothing. If you're trying to convert a string to uppercase, you'll need to use the return value somehow, which neither snippet does.

Comment: Strings are *immutable*, so calling `toUpperCase()` does not (cannot) modify the string to be uppercase. The method *returns* a new string with all uppercase letters, it doesn't update the existing string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Stream.map()` will never run unless you end the pipeline in a [terminal operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps), like `forEach()`. But calling `toUpperCase()` in a `forEach()` won't do anything either, because strings are immutable. `String.toUpperCase()` doesn't change the string; it returns a new one.

If you just want to update the list in-place, you can use

```
list.replaceAll(String::toUpperCase);
```

which actually *replaces* each element with the result of the passed function.

If you want the results in a new list, use the `map()` snippet with a collector:

```
List<String> list2 = list.stream()
        .map(String::toUpperCase)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: OP, please also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35395317/transform-all-elements-of-a-list-of-strings-to-upper-case

Comment: Thanks, shmosel for the reply. But I would like to know how do I make a mind map of these functions rather than relying on the Intellij suggestions for a solution ?

Comment: Study? Practice? I'm not really sure what kind of answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` is an terminal operation that makes a difference through side effects. `map` is a non-terminal operation that makes a direct mapping from one element to another. For example, here is a canonical usage of `forEach`:

```
stream.forEach(System.out::println);
```

This will invoke, on each element of the stream, the equivalent of `System.out.println(element);`. However, the stream will be closed after this, and no operations may be executed on `stream` afterwards. `map`, on the other hand, may be used like this:

```
streamOfObjects.map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In this case, each Object within `streamOfObjects` is mapped to a String, created by invocation of `toString`. Then, the stream of Strings produced by `map` is collected into a List using a Collector.

In any case, I'd suggest using `replaceAll` for this use case, as suggested by @shmosel.

As for how to understand suggestions provided by autocomplete, I would *strongly* suggest reading JavaDocs on the related classes.